# Публичный метод для получения значения в виджете QLineEdit

Tags: qt5, pyqt5

Есть метод, который бы возвращал введенное значение пользователем в поле QLineEdit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше в документация сначала смотрите, а если не нашли в ней ответа или непонятно, уже тут спрашивать. По вашему вопросу ссылка на доку: [QLineEdit::text()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop)

Пример:

```
le = QLineEdit("this text")
print(le.text())  # this text

le.setText("new text")
print(le.text())  # new text
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!